# Two objects from the same company. What is the probability that the second object is defective, given that the first is defective.

Tags: probability

Two companies, $A$ and $B$, produce the same objects.
- The objects that come from the company $A$ are defective with a probability of $0.05$;
- The objects that come from the company $B$ are defective with a probability of $0.01$;
Assuming that someone bought two objects from the same company, with a probability of $50 \%$. If the first object is defective, what is the probability that also the second one is defective?

I have calculated the probability to find the first defective object, that object can come from A or B:
In the formula:

- $D_1$ denote the event "the first defective object";
- $P(A)$ denote the probability to buy an object from the company $A$;
- $P(B)$ denote the probability to buy an object from the company $B$;
- $P(D_1|A)$ denote the probability to buy the first object knowing that come from $A$;
- $P(D_1|B)$ denote the probability to buy the first object knowing that come from $A$;

$\begin{array}{rcl}P(D_1) & = & P(A) \cdot P(D_1 | A) + P(B) \cdot P(D_1|B) \\ & = & 50 \% \cdot 0.05 + 50 \% \cdot 0.01 \\ & = & \frac{0.05}{2} + \frac{0.01}{2} \\ & = & 0.03\end{array}$

but, I am unable to find the second part of the problem.

I have tried to do with a diagram, and I don't know if it is right, I think that those $0.05$ and $0.01$ are means, or approximations, and not exact quantities, i.e. in a bundle of 100 objects I can find 5 but also 0 or 1 etc... defective objects, or better if I consider a numerous bundle of 100 objects I can find a value that reaches 5 defective for each bundle. For this reason the second part of the diagram contains the same quantities, because I think that they are independent.

[image: diagram-es10.png]

Considering what I have done, the probability "also the second is defective given the first is defective" should be:

$\begin{array}{rcl}P(D_2|D_1) & = & 50 \% \cdot 0.05 \cdot 0.05 + 50 \% \cdot 0.01 \cdot 0.01 \\ & = & \frac{0.0025}{2} + \frac{0.0001}{2} \\ & = & 0.0013& \end{array}$

Please, can you help me? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Peter Yes, but I have some difficulties to apply here.

Comment: @Peter No need for Bayes' here. Just the law of total probability, as he has done on the last line. And to me, that seems entirely correct.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Arthur It is not *entirely* correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, you have calculated $\mathsf P(D_1,D_2)= \mathsf P(D_2\mid A)\,\mathsf P(D_1\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(D_2\mid B)\,\mathsf P(D_1\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B)$

That is not what you seek, but you are almost there.   You have also done the other half of the work, so we will just put it together.

$$\mathsf P(D_2\mid D_1)~{=\dfrac{\mathsf P(D_1,D_2)}{\mathsf P(D_1)}\\ = \dfrac{\mathsf P(D_2\mid A)\mathsf P(D_1\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(D_2\mid B)\mathsf P(D_1\mid B)\mathsf P(B)}{\mathsf P(D_1\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(D_1\mid B)\mathsf P(B)}\\=\dfrac{(0.05^2+0.01^2)/2}{(0.05+0.01)/2}\\= \dfrac{0.0013}{0.03}\\=0.04\dot3}$$

---

**Reality check.**   $\mathsf P(D_2\mid A)=0.05$ and $\mathsf P(D_2\mid B)=0.01$.   We should find that $\mathsf P(D_2\mid ``\text{some evidence for which source''})$ lies somewhere between these values, and the evidence that the first item was defective is suggestive that the items are more likely to be from source $A$.

Comment: Can you explain better your notation? you have written $P(D_1, D_2)$, but me $P(D_2|D_1)$, is it the same, or am I wrong?

Comment: and also, in $P(D_2|D_1)$, do you apply Bayes' theorem? But, why $P(D_1, D_2)$ isn't contained within $P(D_1)$?

Comment: Use the *definition of conditional probability*: $\mathsf P(D_2\mid D_1)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(D_1, D_2)}{\mathsf P(D_1)}$, where $\mathsf P(D_1, D_2)$ is the joint probability for the events, $D_1$ and $D_2$ ; that is the event that *both* objects are defective.